# Why does the XContainer.Nodes() and XElement.Attributes() are methods (not properties)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

A theoretical question now.

As I understand methods are used to implement some sort of behavior and properties are used to retain some state of the object.

I found that  `XContainer.Nodes()` as well as `XElement.Attributes()` are implemented as methods, not properties. And, IMHO, other methods that should be implemented as properties: `XNode.ElementsAfterSelf()`, `XNode.ElementsBeforeSelf()` `XNode.NodesAfterSelf()` and so forth.

So, everything that returns `IEnumerable of something` is implemented as method (not property) in Linq to XML.

What is the reason for that? I mean does it serve some specific case or it's just a mistake like for example `String.Split()` method, that returns `char array` instead of more expected `IEnumerable<char>`?

Comment: I would say, that the fact that the methods are lazy (returns only one element at the time using `yield return` instead of solid collection cast to `IEnuemerable`) is the reason why they are methods, not properties.

Comment: You can yield return items of the IEnumerable from the property get accessor in the same way, can't You?

Comment: `String.Split()` predates generics, so `IEnumerable<char>` (or `IEnumerable<string>`) did not exist when it was created.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Microsoft "Choosing Between Properties and Methods"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data. Properties are meant to be used like fields, meaning that properties should not be computationally complex or produce side effects. When it does not violate the following guidelines, consider using a property, rather than a method, because less experienced developers find properties easier to use.

**Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.**

For example, BorderStyle is a property because the style of the border is an attribute of a ListView.

**Do use a property, rather than a method, if the value of the property is stored in the process memory and the property would just provide access to the value.**

You can also read on ["Properties vs Methods" here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzwdh01d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#cpconpropertyusageguidelinesanchor1)

I like this explanation from that last link

> The operation is expensive enough that you want to communicate to the user that they should consider caching the result.